# Laravel ftp working on localhost and not on the server

Tags: php, laravel, ftp, filesystems, laravel-8

I am using working with a ftp server to get the list of the files and then convert them to CSV.

Now the whole thing is working as desired on my localhost except when I shifted my project to a server it has stopped working.

My `config\filesystem.php`

```
'ftp' => [
        'driver' => 'ftp',
        'host' => 'my.host.address.is',
        'username' => 'ftpuser',
        'password' => 'Ftppassword',
        'passive' => false,
        // Optional FTP Settings...
        // 'port' => 21,
        // 'root' => '',
        // 'passive' => true,
        // 'ssl' => true,
        // 'timeout' => 30,
    ],
```

I have also tried changing `'passive'=true`, but the output is same.

My controller.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use File;
class CsvController extends Controller
{

   public function index()
   { 
      echo "atleast I am here right-/okayioio-12:26";
      $fi=Storage::disk('ftp')->files('hello/xml/');
      dd($fi);
   }
}
```

The Output I am getting on **localhost**

[image: localhost]

The Output I am getting on **server**

[image: server]

(P.S the echo part is different as but the file part is same.)

Comment: Did you refresh cache after changing config? E.g php artisan optimize

Comment: Is there a reason why the echo prior the to dd is different?

Comment: @AaronT no no its just I update the echo code on my local.

Comment: For the ftp connection, both local and server are using the exact same username and password? Trying to see whether it is a case of different user and default home folders.

Comment: @RolandRuul Yes i ran the command `php artisan config:cache` but still the result is same

Comment: Did you test if your server is able to connect to your ftp-server at all?

Comment: try only `php artisan config:clear`, and make sure your connection with FTP is established.

Comment: One more thing, are you sure you have the same file structure at the server? Maybe there's no folder with name "hello" can you check that?

Comment: make sure about config, check with `dump(config('filesystems.disks.ftp'))`

Comment: Test FTP using CLI on your production server. It may be a port blocked issue. Do you have anything in Laravel  and nginx/apache logs?

Comment: confirm a port number if default use 22

Comment: Have you tried checking if the folder even exists? `Storage::disk('ftp')->exists('hello/xml');`